# MyBatis - How to write <if> statement under <foreach>?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I loop a collection, and only when the item of the collection is not null, then it will be inserted into the DB, the snippet code like that:

```
<foreach collection="ids" item="id" separator=",">
    <if test="id!= null">
       (#{id})
    </if>
</foreach>
```

the statement run failed, it said "Parameter 'id' not found.", the I change the  statement :

```
<if test="#{id}!= null">
```

It failed also, so how can I write the  statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the version from 3.2.8 to 3.3.0, it will be fixed.